# how can I print on shell the items inside a list on C#?

Tags: c#, list

I want to run this on Main but for some reason, the RCP error shows as does not exist in current content. How do you fix this?

The error appears to be in Line 56, "SaleReceipts.ForEach(i => rcp.PrintReceipt());"

```
        List<eReceipt> SaleReceipts = new List<Receipt>();
        string finalanswer = "y";
        
        
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Customer ID:");
            int customerid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of Cogs:");
            int cogs = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of gears");
            int gears = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Receipt rcp = new Receipt(customerid, cogs, gears);
            rcp.CalculateNetAmount();
            rcp.CalculateTaxAmount();
            rcp.CalculateTotal();
            SaleReceipts.Add(rcp);
            rcp.PrintReceipt();
            

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to generate another receipt? (y/n)");
            finalanswer = Console.ReadLine();              
                            
        }
        while (finalanswer == "y") ;


        SaleReceipts.ForEach(i => rcp.PrintReceipt());
```

Comment: You defined `rcp` inside the `do`. It doesn't exist outside. Read about [scopes.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: You used `rcp` instead of `i` which I suppose you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR**

Change

```
SaleReceipts.ForEach(i => rcp.PrintReceipt());
```

to

```
SaleReceipts.ForEach(i => i.PrintReceipt());
```

**Answer**

With the current structure of your code you are calling rcp.PrintReceipt() for each occurrence in the SaleReceipts List.  You defined the input parameter for the ForEach statement as i and therefore you must call *.PrintReceipt* on i rather than *rcp*.

Example:

```
SaleReceipts.ForEach(i => i.PrintReceipt());
```

The reason that you cannot use *rcp* is becase it is scoped to the do/while loop.  Because the variable *rcp* is defined within the loop it does not exist outside the loop.

The i that you declare in the [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netcore-3.1) is actually an [input parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) to the function that you are defining on the right hand side of your [lambda operator (=>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) and as such is essentially a reference to the object that ForEach is referencing on each pass.